# Отсутствует оператор << соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

```
#include <iostream>


class X
{
public:
    X(int b)
    {
        this->b = b;
    }
    
    ~X()
    {
    }
    
    int b;

    friend X operator+ (const X&, const X&);

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, X&);
};

X operator+ (const X& left, const X& right)
{
    X ret = left;
    ret.b += right.b;
    return ret;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, X& lst)
{
    out << lst.b;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    X a(10);
    X b(20);
    std::cout << a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

вылетает

> error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый
> операнд типа "X" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Что в данном случае неверно? Оператор `+` возвращает как раз `X` который подходит под перегрузку `<<`

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const List& lst)` не нужно разве делать?

Comment: сделал пример кода минимальным. @Zhinar а что поменяет `const` перед `List& lst` ?

Comment: Надо не только минимальным, но и воспроизводимым

Comment: Так вам уже сказали:  a + b  вернет объект Х, но  пока функция (программа) нигде его не хранит, он будет временным объектом, а для временного объекта у вас нет оператора, поскольку оператор написан для не константной ссылки, а к временному объекту можно  по константной ссылке ссылаться. Добавьте const в операторе и вперед...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все решается одним словом `const`. Вы неправы в одном -

> Оператор + возвращает как раз X который подходит под перегрузку <<

он вернет *временный* `X`, `rvalue`, который никак под эту перегрузку не подходит. А подходит под эту:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const X&);
```